# Nested subscript in RMarkdown?

Tags: r-markdown

Is it possible to have a nested subscript in RMarkdown?

In LaTeX I can use `A_{B_{C_{D}}}` but I'm not sure what the bracket equivalent would be for RMarkdown. `A~B~C~D~~~` does not work...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In RMarkdown, you can include latex inline by enclosing the expression with `$`. That is, the following included in your RMarkdown document:

```
$A_{B_{C_{D}}}$
```

will render the nested subscripts as

[image]